# После выполнения php скрипта, выполняется замена содержимого формы, как выполнить ещё одну замену чтобы всё обработалось снова?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Выполняю вот такой скрипт.

```
   <?php
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        if (isset($_POST['name'])) {$name = $_POST['name'];}
        if (isset($_POST['phone'])) {$phone = $_POST['phone'];}
        if (isset($_POST['formData'])) {$formData = $_POST['formData'];}
        if (isset($_POST['formCalc'])) {$formCalc = $_POST['formCalc'];}
        $to = "222@rr.com";
        $to = "asd@asd.ru";
        $headers  = "From: " . strip_tags($sendfrom) . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($sendfrom) . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8 \r\n";
        $subject = "$formData";
        if ($formCalc != null && $formCalc != 0 ) {
            $message = "$formData<br> <b>Имя пославшего:</b> $name <br><b>Телефон:</b> $phone <br> <b>Результат вычислений</b> $formCalc";
        } else {
            $message = "$formData<br> <b>Имя пославшего:</b> $name <br><b>Телефон:</b> $phone";
        }

        $send = mail ($to, $subject, $message, $headers, "-fpotolki@jurgomel.ru");
        if ($send == 'true')
        { echo '<center><p class="success">Спасибо за отправку вашего сообщения!</p></center>';
        }
        else 
        {
        echo '<center><p class="fail"><b>Ошибка. Сообщение не отправлено!</b></p></center>';
        }
    } else {
        http_response_code(403);
        echo "Попробуйте еще раз";
    }?>
```

После, через js, обновляю на нажатие крестика, форму. И когда собираюсь совершить снова отправку сообщения - обновляется страница. Что я делаю не так?

```
$('#modal_close, #overlay').click( function(){ 
        $('#modal_form')
            .animate({opacity: 0, top: '45%'}, 200,
                function(){ 
                    $(this).css('display', 'none');
                    $('#overlay').fadeOut(400);
                }
            );
        $(".form_modal").html('<form id="form">   <h2 id="modal1Title" style="font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold; color: #c7d9e7;' +
            'text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 21, 57, 0.7);" >Оставьте ваши контактные данные и наш консультант свяжется <br>с вами</h2> ' +
            '<input type="text" class="putName" name="name" placeholder="Ваше ваше имя" required>'+
            '<input name="phone" type="tel" class="putPhone" placeholder="Введите номер телефона" required>'+
            '<input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn" value="ОТПРАВИТЬ">' +
            '<input type="hidden" name="formData" value="Заявка с сайта">'+
            '<input type="hidden" name="formCalc" id="Calc-feedback" value="0">'+
            '</form>');
    });
```

Вот сам код на сайте:

```
 <div id="modal_form">
       <span id="modal_close"></span> 
      <div class="form_modal"> 
          <form id="form">
            <h2 id="modal1Title" style="font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold; color: #c7d9e7; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 21, 57, 0.7);" >Оставьте ваши контактные данные и наш консультант свяжется <br>с вами</h2>
            <input type="text" class="putName" name="name" placeholder="Ваше ваше имя" required>
            <input name="phone" type="tel" class="putPhone" placeholder="Введите номер телефона" required>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn" value="ОТПРАВИТЬ">
            <input type="hidden" name="formData" value="Заявка с сайта потолки Буда-Кошелёво">
            <input type="hidden" name="formCalc" id="Calc-feedback" value="0">
          </form>
         </div>
        </div>
        <div id="overlay"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что вы пересоздаете элемент. Тогда AJAX работать не будет. Проще так: формы вроде как одинаковые, просто очищайте инпуты.

**ВТОРОЙ ВАРИАНТ:**

```
<form id="form">
```

замените на

```
<form id="form" class="form_modal">
```

удалите:

```
<div class="form_modal"> и его закрывающий </div>
```

и в JS удалите:

```
<form id="form"> и </form>
```

Comment: В php после выполнения функции mail выполняется условный оператор, в котором заменяется содержимое формы.

Comment: Дело в том, что у меня обработка выполняется через ajax
   $("form").submit(function () {
 var formID = $(this).attr('id');
 var formNm = $('#' + formID);
 $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'mail.php',
  data: formNm.serialize(),
  success: function (data) {
   // Вывод текста результата отправки
   $(formNm).html(data); 
  },
  error: function (jqXHR, text, error) {
   // Вывод текста ошибки отправки
   $(formNm).html(error);         
  }
 });
 return false;
 });

Comment: @ВикторТимошков ну дела-то не меняет. вы заменяете ВСЮ форму. Добавил в ответ второй вариант

Comment: Да, действительно, всё работает, вы помогли решить мою проблему.

Answer (score 1):

Похоже что ваша формы отправляет данные... в никуда.  Попробуйте добавить тегу form атрибуты method и action. Укажите в action URL своего скрипта и форма отправит запрос по нужному адресу.

Comment: Для атрибутов `method` и `action` по умолчанию заданы значения `get` и `адрес текущей страницы` соответственно)